# Arrays - El Numero Menor de Cada Columna Java

Tags: java, array

Intento obtener el numero menor en cada columna, pero no lo consigo.
 Necesito ayuda por favor.

```
int menorColumna = matriz1[0][0];
String pos = "";
for (int i = 0; i < matriz1[0].length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < matriz1.length; j++) {
    if (matriz1[i][j] < menorColumna) {
      menorColumna = matriz1[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola, recuerda que estás en S.O. en español. Edita tu pregunta para que se adapte al idioma del sitio. Saludos

Comment: Perdona, ya esta corregido! Gracias @MauricioContreras

Answer (score 1):

Como quieres el menor de cada columna necesitarías un arreglo de forma de tener un valor mínimo para cada colunma por lo que hay que cambiar:

```
int menorColumna
```

por:

```
int[] menorColumna = new int[matriz1.length]
```

y después modificar la recorrida de para adaptar los cambios quedando algo así:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matriz1[0].length; i++) {
  menorColumna[i] = matriz1[i][0];//valor minimo inicial para la columna i
  for (int j = 0; j < matriz1.length; j++) {
    if (matriz1[i][j] < menorColumna[i]) {
      menorColumna[i] = matriz1[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer, menorColumna la estás comparando con todos los elementos del array. Por tanto, al final de la ejecución, su resultado será igual al menor numero de todo el array matriz1.

Si quieres sacar el menor valor de cada columna, tendrás que crear un array Int de longitud igual a las columnas de matriz1. Para instanciar la variable, se utiliza un bucle for:

```
int menorColumna[] = new int[matriz1[0].length]; //Suponiendo que cada fila tiene el mismo numero de elementos

for(int k = 0; k < matriz1[0].length; k++){menorColumna[k] = matriz1[0][k];}
```

Para obtener el menor numero de cada columna hay que hacer 2 bucles: uno que se encargue de cambiar de filas y otro que se encargue de las columnas.

```
for(int i = 0; i < matriz1[0].length; i++){ //Cambio de columna
    for(int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++){ //Cambio de fila
        if(matriz1[j][i] < menorColumna[i]){ //Encontrar el menor
            menorColumna[i] = matriz1[j][i];
        }
    }
}
```

Lo he probado y me ha funcionado, espero haberte sido de ayuda.